# Значение переменной увеличивается неправильно

Tags: c++

Мне непонятно почему в конце выводится вместо 12 0 пробовал вместо i++ писать *i++ результат не меняется.

> http://cpp.sh/95faq

Comment: дык у вас UB, потому что в конце вместо `(*i)++;` вы написали `i++;`, указатель куда-то сдвинулся и выводится 0

Comment: @goldstar_labs Теперь ясно почему Visual Studio кидал ошибку связанную с памятью.

Comment: Код следует добавлять прямо в вопрос!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int* i = new int;
   *i = 10;
   cout<<*i<<"\n";
   *i=*i+1;
   cout<<*i<<"\n";
   (*i)++;
   cout<<*i;
}
```

Output:

```
10
11
12
```